# How to change cursor in Cesium?

Tags: javascript, extjs, cesiumjs, webgl-earth

I am trying to change the cursor when it mouses over certain cesium objects. I am using a mouse over listener and that part is working (found out by using `debugger;`). But when I mouse over it (and according to the Firefox debugger the variable name is changed), the cursor stays the same. Google and Cesium's API documentation have yielded no help. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
var pickedObject = scene.pick(movement.endPosition);
if(Cesium.defined(pickedObject) && (pickedObject.id)) {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    debugger;
} else {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    debugger;
}
```

Before this code runs, Firefox says `document.body.style.cursor = ""` .
At the first `debugger;` it says `document.body.style.cursor="pointer"`.
At the second `debugger;` it says `document.body.style.cursor="default"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the third line to the following changed the cursor to the pointer:

```
Ext.get(scope.id).setStyle('cursor', 'pointer');
```

Changing the sixth line to the following changed it back:

```
Ext.get(scope.id).setStyle('cursor', 'grab');
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using any external library it would be like this:

```
viewer._container.style.cursor = "crosshair";
```

or reset to default

```
viewer._container.style.cursor = "default";
```